# Edit awk command to ignore specific line pattern

Tags: awk

I'm using an awk command to filter out duplicate lines, I love it as its fast and clean. However I need it to ignore lines that contain just (and only - because some lines contain + signs and other stuff, and I do want them still checked for duplication) a plus sign, i.e. +

I can do this using additional lines of code and some temp files but..
How can I edit this single line command to do this? so I can keep it clean and fast.

The current code filters any line that is a duplicate of another line anywhere in another file, this is great, but can it ignore + only lines

This is the code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]' file2 file1 > FilteredFile
```

file1:

```
1234  
+      
adcs   
abba   
+  
542221   
+  
jabba
```

file2:

```
jingle  
1234      
+  
haad  
+    
rigor     
abba     
wiggle    
+  
542221     
jabba
```

output:

```
jingle  
+       
haad    
+  
rigor   
+     
wiggle
```

Comment: Not clear, please do mention sample of both the files along with sample of expected output and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has added more details so adding this solution now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR && $0!="+"{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)'  file1 file2
```

---

---

I am not sure why you are using `FNR==NR` that is the condition when we are reading 2 or more Input_files we are reading. So I am assuming you need to get uniq values along with removing lines which have `+` in them if I got it correctly then could you please try following.

```
awk '$0!="+" && !a[$0]++' Input_file
```

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, I should have been more clear in the question, you are correct I am reading 2 files at once. I have corrected my question to clear this up

Comment: @Giles, np, could you please EDIT your post with both fiels values sample ones and expected output sample too and let us know then?

Comment: @Giles, could you please check my EDIT solution and let me know?

Comment: I liked better when you had the `!/\+/` as part of the pattern --- why move it to an `if` inside the action?

Comment: @jas, sure jas I have edited it now, thank you for your valuable comments here, cheers buddy.

Comment: Per the OPs requirements (`need it to ignore lines that contain just (and only - because some lines contain + signs and other stuff, and I do want them still checked for duplication) a plus sign, i.e. +`) the condition needs to be `$0!="+"` or `/[^+]/` or similar, not `!/\+/`. The OP seems to rush to accept answers without testing or thinking about them - odd....

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for letting know Ed sir, corrected it now, thanks a TON. I went by samples part only so written that. Or may be we can write like `!/^\+$/` too IMHO?